# Yii2 - Bad Request (#400) - Missing required parameters: id

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, bad-request

CommentController:

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    $model = new Comment();

    var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());

     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
     {
        $model->user_id = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $model->created_at = time();
        $model->updated_at = time();
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(Url::to(['post/view', 'id'=>$model->post_id])); 
     }

    return $this->redirect(Url::to(['/post/index'])); 
}
```

If I pass as `false` to `$model->save()` the data gets stored in the database with no value in the foreign key field 'post_id' but still doesn't redirect me to the correct page.

New to yii and relatively new to software development, any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: I guess you don't set `$model->post_id`

Answer (score 0):

It redirects you to `post/view` - means `PostController` - `actionView($id)`, but without param `$id`, which is required in `actionView($id)`. That's why you get 400 missing param error. You have to add this param - for now if you add `false` to `save()` method and it is saved without `post_id` - you can't redirect user to `post/view` because you didn't passed `id` of this object in `GET`

To avoid such things you should check if `$model` is really saved by `if($model->save())` and if, redirect user to view.

Comment: Hi my PostController actionView looks like:

  public function actionView($id)
    {   
        $comment = new Comment(); 
        
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id), 
            'comment'  => $comment, // passing comment form to /post/view.php
            
        ]);
    }
I'm not sure where to go from here I am a complete newbie. 
P.s thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like below in your controller.If id exist this will keep the id value otherwise it defines and keep it as empty.

```
public function actionView($id='') {
  //
}
```

Comment: Did you try like this? @Kyle Dyson

Comment: Yes thank you! However now I am getting "Not Found (#404). And still there is nothing saving to the database

Comment: you given the path as `post/view` which means In PostController you should have actionView function.It is there?

Comment: And outside if loop you have mentioned `/post/index`?

Comment: Yes it is there, I will add the code for it now to the post

Comment: you should mention `post/index` instead of `/post/index`

Comment: And also it is going to `view` or `index`?